# PHY Link only establishing 10 Mbps speed when both devices 100 Mbps capable

Tags: ethernet, microchip, high-frequency, network, phy

I've designed a circuit board with a Microchip switch (KSZ9897) going to a Ethernet-to-VDSL module (LX200V20).

The PHY ports between the two devices are connected using a transformerless connection as shown on Figure 4 in this application note (http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/AppNotes/ANLAN120-UNG.pdf).

By default with auto-negotiation & auto MDI-X enabled, the switch establishes a 10 Mbps, full-duplex link. I am expecting a 100 Mbps link since both devices are 100-BaseTX compatible and I've confirmed that by decoding the LCW (link-code-word) from their fast link pulses.

I have also tried a forced speed connection (disabling auto-negotiation). For 100 Mbps & Full-duplex, I can see some idle traffic on both RX and TX pairs, but the link does not come up. For 10 Mbps & Full-duplex, the link does come up and work. I have also tried disabling auto MDI-X, but that does not seem to change much either.

My question is what could be causing the link to only establish at 10 Mbps? I have attached some scope pics to help isolate the problem. The scopes are all from one of the RX/TX pairs between the switch and the AC coupling caps.

- Scope 1) Forced 100 Mbps idle traffic
- Scope 2) LCW from VDSL module (left burst), LCW from switch (right burst)
- Scope 3) NLP (single burst of LCW) from VDSL module

[image: Forced 100 Mbps idle traffic]
[image: LCW from VDSL module (left burst), LCW from switch (right burst)]
[image: NLP (single burst of LCW) from VDSL module]

Comment: Try half-duplex in case of crosstalk.

Comment: Have you impedance controlled the lines between the PHYs? Lets see pic of the layout

Comment: Some output stages are not compatible. Some require external resistors as well. Some chips require changing their output drivers to act differently how they source and sink current (clasd A vs class B). In addition these may recommend disabling autonegotiation and just force the link to 100M and fullduplex, as 10M might require different capacitor values and/or biasing. 100nF caps have worked for me, with all the above tricks.

Comment: examine photo #3, the fall time of the BLUE is 3/4 of a 50nanosec division, or 37 nanoseconds. Inverse of 37nS is 22MHz.

Comment: @analogsystemsrf What does the inverse fall time of the NLP have to do with the link speed achieved?

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 Half-duplex is same issue. The only case of forced speed which works is 10 Mbps.

Comment: @laptop2d Yes it has been impedance controlled. And the same layout design has worked before with the same transformerless connection with another switch PHY.